# What should I do to enable Data.List.Zipper in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am in need for a zipper over a list. I am not sure how to get it linked to my project. The document page doesn't say much on that: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListZipper-1.2.0.1/docs/Data-List-Zipper.html

Would you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a package from `hackage`, which you can install with the `cabal` utility. More information on that utility, including install instructions, can be found [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install).

Once you have cabal installed, simply do

```
cabal install ListZipper
```

and, in the file you want to use it in,

```
import Data.List.Zipper
```